# How to link multiple images together with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, hyperlink

I'm trying to create an image hierarchy using hyperlinks so we can jump around from different years and view different image directories. As of now, we can press the thumbnail and it advances to the next image, i would like to learn how to add additional hrefs to the class path which I assume can happen, I tried to inject a few differnet snipts of code into the current class path but its still not functioning how I would like.
Thank you

```
DOCTYPE HTML>

-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Our Family</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">
                        <h1><a href="index.html"><strong>OUR</strong> Family</a></h1>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#footer" class="icon solid fa-info-circle">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </header>

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>2022</h2>
                            <p>Trip to Texas</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="images/fulls/02.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>2021</h2>
                            <p>Priest Lake</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="images/fulls/03.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>2020</h2>
                            <p>North Arizona</p>
                        </article>
!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer" class="panel">
                        <div class="inner split">
                            <div>
                                <section>
                                    <h2>text goes here</p>
                                </section>
                                <section>
                                    <h2>Follow me on ...</h2>
                                    <ul class="icons">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-linkedin-in"><span class="label">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </section>
                                <p class="copyright">
                                    &copy; Unttled. Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <section>
                                    <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                                    <form method="post" action="#">
                                        <div class="fields">
                                            <div class="field half">
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="field half">
                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="field">
                                                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" value="Send" class="primary" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </form>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>

            </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not too clear what you're asking. Can you re-phrase your question and maybe even add a complete code sample, not just an incomplete snippet.

Comment: Thank you for responding obscure, I re-phrase and added the complete index

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!-- Is this what you mean -->
<a href="#">
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /><br/>
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /><br/>
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /><br/>
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /><br/>
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /><br/>
</a>

<!-- I think this is the better way -->
<a href="#">
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```